# Azure Powershell Positional Parameter error

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I'm trying to do a deployment using powershell. Both parameter and template file are stored in blob storage, but I get the error below before it even tries to download the blobs.

`New-AzResourceGroupDeployment : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'newdeployment-878059'. At C:\Temp\New-Deployment\deploy-core.ps1:86 char:1`

The code I use is below

```
$vnetRG = "rg-vnet"
$vpnRG = "rg-vpn"
$fwRG = "rg-fw"
$btnRG = "rg-bastion"
$loc = "west europe"

New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -Name = "newdeployment-$random"-ResourceGroupName "rg-vnet" `
  -TemplateParameterFile "$PSScriptRoot\core.parameters.json" -TemplateUri = $templateFileUri `
  -vpnResourceGroupName $rgRG -vpnResourceGroupName $vpnRG -fwResourceGroupName $fwRG  -btnResourceGroupName $btnRG
```

I'm trying to deploy multiple resources to various resource groups in one subscription.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Remove the `=` after the parameter name. Also, looking at [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azresourcegroupdeployment?view=azps-4.6.1), I don't see parameters `vpnResourceGroupName`, `fwResourceGroupName` or `btnResourceGroupName` on that cmdlet. Not only that, but you have added `vpnResourceGroupName` twice.. And if I may suggest, have a look at [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) parameters for cmdlets that can take a lot of parameters.

Comment: Thanks @Theo cannot believe I did that. Thanks for your help and I was using splatting but spread everything out trying to isolate the issue. Thanks again. Could you mark your reply as an aswer and I'll accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here my comment as answer

In your code, you have added an `=` character between some of the parameter names and the actual value to use for that parameter.
In PowerShell you assign a value to a parameter with a space character between the two.

Also, there are parameters used that (according to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azresourcegroupdeployment?view=azps-4.6.1)) don't exist for that cmdlet, like `vpnResourceGroupName`, `fwResourceGroupName` and `btnResourceGroupName`. To me, they sound like variables mistakenly added as parameter with the leading `$` stripped off?

For cmdlets that can potentially use a large number of parameters, I'd recommend using [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting), to keep the code clean and easy to maintain.

Something like:

```
$splatParams = @{
    Name                  = "newdeployment-$random"
    ResourceGroupName     = "rg-vnet"
    TemplateParameterFile = "$PSScriptRoot\core.parameters.json"
    TemplateUri           = $templateFileUri
}

New-AzResourceGroupDeployment @splatParams
```